# PL/SQL raise_application_error with SQL%NOTFOUND

Tags: plsql

I am trying write a procedure that is checking that people in some of my tables are assigned properly. This is the first procedure in a package. If everybody is assigned properly the SQL will return no records. If people are not assigned the SQL will return those people not assigned.

```
...

BEGIN

    FOR R_PEOPLE IN C_PEOPLE

        LOOP

        IF SQL%NOTFOUND THEN
            RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20002, 'ALL PEOPLE ASSIGNED, PROCEED');
        END IF;

       -- When data is found, should raise exception and stop billing process

        IF SQL%FOUND THEN
            RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'MISSING PEOPLE');
        END IF;

        END LOOP;

END;
```

What I'm trying to do is raise two different messages out to the end user who will be running this in `TOAD`. If no results are returned, everyone is assigned, I want to output the first `IF` statement "ALL PEOPLE ASSIGNED, PROCEED". If the SQL returns records then ideally I want the second `IF` to execute "MISSING People".

Currently, when people are missing, I get the "MISSING PEOPLE" output to the user. But if everyone is already assigned, I just get "Procedure Complete".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FOR R_PEOPLE IN C_PEOPLE

    LOOP

    IF SQL%NOTFOUND THEN
    -- ^^^^^^^^^^^^
    -- this can never be true since if there was no row,
    -- you won't enter the loop
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20002, 'ALL PEOPLE ASSIGNED, PROCEED');
    END IF;

    ...
```

This can't work as, if there was no match, you won't execute the loop body even once.

---

I don't know how is your query, but maybe you could rewrite that using a `COUNT(*)` an use the result (either 0 or non-zero) to raise the appropriate exception ?

Something *like* that, maybe:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO RESULT FROM .... WHERE ..... ;
IF RESULT = 0
THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20002, 'ALL PEOPLE ASSIGNED, PROCEED');
ELSE
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'MISSING PEOPLE');
END IF;
```

Comment: I could rewrite it yes, originally it was just returning the highest person_id. So that would be no hassle. Thanks

Comment: RESULT == 0, should be `= 0` (I think)

Comment: @Jonnny Oups ! Wrong language. Thank you.